# Table border spacing with div

Tags: html, css

[image: Table]

Hello,

I am newbie on CSS, and I am going to design a pricing table with div(table-less). I use below css. My main problem is customized space between columns and rows.

When I add "border-spacing" four sides of cell would have border. But As you can see in picture I need different space on each side of cells.

For example border space on top and bottom 0, border space on left and right 10px. But I can not find any solution.

css style:

```css
.Table{
    display: table;
}
.Title{
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
}
.Heading{
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.Row{
    display: table-row;
}
.Cell{
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Full_width{
    width: 100%;
}

.No_border{
    border: none;
}

.mostpopular_tag{
    background-color:#F25050;
    color: #fff;
}

.pricing_table_header{
    line-height: 21px;
    background-color: #181818;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And Table HTML structure is like below:

```
<div class="Table full_width">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border mostpopular_tag">
            <p>Most Popular</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p></p>
        </div>              
    </div>
    <div class="Heading ">
        <div class="Cell No_border pricing_table_header">
            <p>Heading 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border pricing_table_header">
            <p>Heading 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border pricing_table_header">
            <p>Heading 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p>Row 1 Column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p>Row 1 Column 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p>Row 1 Column 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p>Row 2 Column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell No_border">
            <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is demo of my table: http://jsfiddle.net/2rFfL/

Comment: "design a pricing table with div(table-less)" - by using "display: table" you're using tables. You've just changed the tag.

Comment: Well, People continuously table is slow to load and use div. Do I found a wrong solution?

Comment: Your solution can't be considered "table-less".You are using "display: table" in your code.

Comment: Look on to bootstrap and his classes. You can also look on implementations of column layout (that's what it is in smaller scope).

Comment: Is there any place teach it in simple language. Because I am a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-spacing` accepts two values. If you supply both values, as in `border-spacing: 10px 0;`, then the first applies horizontally and the second vertically.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/2rFfL/1/

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. I did not know it can be supplied by two value. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The border, margin, and padding properties have different versions for "all over" versus "each side"

So, border could be done like this:

```
border-width: 3px;
```

Or it can be done like this (first number is top, second right, third bottom, fourth left):

```
border-width: 3px 5px 2px 10px;
```

Or, you can specify each like this:

```
border-top-width: 3px;
border-right-width: 5px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-left-width: 10px;
```

Comment: Hello Aaron. May you show me how to use it because I use it in any possible way that I know. But no success.

Comment: sure, in your CSS above, in the **.Cell** class, replace border-width: thin, with **border-width: 3px 4px 5px 6px**. Where **3px** is the top number, **4px** is the right number, **5px** is the bottom number and **6px** is the left number. Replace the numbers with the actual amounts you want but leave the **px** there for pixels, or **%** for percentages. Make sense?